# Prior art for athletic gear with padded seat area

Tags: prior-art-request, us20120222191, apparel

[Patent application #20120222191](http://www.google.com/patents/us20120222191) titled "Sports garment with a seat pad, in particular for cycling" claims to have a unique method for attaching a padded section to a spandex cycling short. Here's claim 1 from the patent:

> A skin-tight sports garment comprising at least a portion acting as trousers and a seat pad located in a crotch area of the garment, the seat pad comprising a front attachment region to the garment and a rear attachment region to the garment, a central portion of the seat pad being free from attachments to the garment and thus forming a loose bridge portion of the seat pad in the inner crotch area of the garment.

Having worn them myself, I know that padded sports garments have been around for years and there must be prior art for such.

**What prior art addresses padded sports garments - particularly cycling shorts?**

Comment: Are they patenting the "Loose bridge portion of the seat pad"?

Comment: I think the "front and rear attachments" portion of claim 1 is the sailient part. All cycling shorts I've seen have the chamois stiched in all around, rather than attaching at just the front and rear portions.

Comment: Here's a link to a whole bunch of cycling shorts.. http://www.performancebike.com/bikes/SubCategory_10052_10551_400065_-1_400000_400020

Answer (score 2):

To me this seems like what motorcycle clothing has been doing forever. In jackets and pants they have padding inserts that can be removed and/or replaced. They are primarily for protection in case of a fall but to me this sounds like the exact same proposal. Just in a different area of the body.